# How to remove subgroup labels from legend?

Tags: qgis, print-composer, legend

In print composer legend is it possible to turn off the display of the group name in the legend?
[image]

So it shouldn't show the DSC_Roads and other items marked with X

Comment: Bit late to the party, but [this answer does the trick](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/223001/setting-layer-name-in-composer-legend-as-hidden-using-pyqgis).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can just go to Legend items and right-click the subgroup that you want to hide and click on Hidden. This will do what you are asking for.

[image]

Comment: thanks. I was trying to uncheck subgroup but really you just need to click hidden.

Comment: Is there a way of doing this with python?

Comment: I not sure if you can do it in Python. I have not tried that before.