# Setting layer name in composer legend as "Hidden" using PyQGIS?

Tags: pyqgis, print-composer, legend

Is there a way to hide a layer name in the composer legend using pyqgis as we do from the legend properties (see picture)?

[image]

The only way I've found so far is by changing the layer name in the composer legend but it will also change it in the Layers list and I don't want that.

This is the code I used:

```
        itemLlegend = composition.getComposerItemById('Legend')
        modelindex=itemLlegend.modelV2().index(0, 0)
        itemLlegend.modelV2().setFlag(QgsLayerTreeModel.AllowNodeRename)
        itemLlegend.modelV2().setData(modelindex,'')
        itemLlegend.updateLegend()
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I had this problem too. My friend who is working for QGIS told me how.

What you can do is:

take the QgsLayerTreeLayer from the model (if you haven't include it in the model):

```
tree_layer = itemLlegend.modelV2().rootGroup().addLayer(layer)
```

If your layer is already in the model, just iterate rootGroup and grab your `tree_layer`.

After you got your tree layer:

```
from qgis.core import QgsLegendRenderer, QgsComposerLegendStyle
QgsLegendRenderer.setNodeLegendStyle(
    tree_layer, QgsComposerLegendStyle.Hidden)
```

This will add style to your `tree_layer` it will now will be hidden by the renderer (but, just the `Visitors` text will be hidden).

Comment: Can this code change the layer name of the legend?

Comment: Yes, but I don't see why you prefer this over changing the layer name directly in the layer.

Answer (score 5):

The updated recipe for QGIS 3.x

```py
from qgis.core import QgsLayoutItemLegend, QgsLegendRenderer, QgsLegendStyle, QgsProject

project = QgsProject.instance()
manager = project.layoutManager()
layout = manager.layoutByName('print1') # Your layout name


# If only one legend within the layout
layoutItemLegend = [i for i in layout.items() if isinstance(i,  QgsLayoutItemLegend)][0]
# Could also use the following if you defined an id 'mylegend' for the QgsLayoutItemLegend (commented here)
# layoutItemLegend = layout.itemById('mylegend')
model = layoutItemLegend.model()
tree_legend = model.rootGroup()

# Desactivate auto refresh of the legend
layoutItemLegend.setAutoUpdateModel(False)
layoutItemLegend.updateLegend()


# Then do to apply change for the first element (group or layer)
QgsLegendRenderer.setNodeLegendStyle(
    tree_legend.children()[0], QgsLegendStyle.Hidden)
```